# Excel hangs when runs VBA in Module

Tags: vba, excel

Excel rookie here. I'm trying a very simple task: copying and pasting cells. The Excel will go into "non responding" once the VBA runs. The code was running at one point, but as I developed more lines, Excel stopped responding. I comment out the rest of the line and only run the lines shown below, Excel still hangs. Any ideas? Thanks!

Also, I'm writing the codes in the module in Excel.

```
Sub EDRII()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim EDR As Worksheet, Lookup As Worksheet, FA As Worksheet
Set EDR = Sheets("for edr II")
Set Lookup = Sheets("Lookup")
Set FA = Sheets("FA_Segment_Region")

Sheets(EDR).Activate
Range("B6:X10").Copy Range("B5:X9")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[Excel xlsm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufw6G.png)

Comment: `Sheets(EDR).Activate` should be `EDR.Activate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some pointers:

1. Indent your code so it's easier to follow (minor point in your example)
2. Fully qualify your references (`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(), EDR.Range(), etc`)
3. Rather than copying and pasting, use `.Value`

Your code was breaking down because you were trying to activate EDR with `Sheets(EDR).Activate` which should just be `EDR.Activate`. Either way, when you take into account the points above you see that you don't need to `Activate` anything anyway!

```
Sub EDRII()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim EDR As Worksheet, Lookup As Worksheet, FA As Worksheet
    Set EDR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("for edr II")
    Set Lookup = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lookup")
    Set FA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FA_Segment_Region")

    EDR.Range("B5:X9").Value = EDR.Range("B6:X10").Value

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This works!! What's the difference between .value and copy|paste?

Comment: No problem. Firstly, it's quicker! In some ways you could think of it as the difference between setting the value of one cell equal to the other (e.g. `=A1`) vs. copying and pasting. Just two different methods.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `EDR` to be a `Worksheet` and assigned it to be a reference to the sheet called "for edr II".

When you try to use it later, in the line saying

```
Sheets(EDR).Activate
```

you are using `EDR` in a spot where VBA is expecting a `String` or an `Integer` (or `Long`).

That line should simply say

```
EDR.Activate
```

---

It's also a good idea to avoid `Activate` and `Select` whenever possible so, rather than activating the sheet, you could just use

```
EDR.Range("B6:X10").Copy EDR.Range("B5:X9")
```

for the `Copy` statement.

Comment: This helps too. Thanks for the tips!